# Lisp evaluate variable in macro expression

Tags: macros, lisp, elisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have the following function (I am a very beginner at Lisp):

```
(defun my-fun (a b)
    (my-commandsend-and-reply-macro (cmd)
      (:reply (ok result)
              (do-something a b result)))
)
```

where my-commandsend-and-reply-macro is a macro written by another programmer. I am unable to modify it.

my-commandsend-and-reply-macro sends a command (in this example cmd) to a server process (it is written in another programming language) and then waits for its answer.
The answer is processed then in the macro using the user-given ":reply part of the code". The list (ok result) is a kind of pattern, in the macro a destructuring-bind destructures and binds the proper parts of the answer to ok and result (ok is just a flag). After this the other user-given lines of the ":reply part" are excuted. (for result processing)

I would like to do the following:

1, send a command like to the other process (this is ok)

2, call a function (like do-something) using the result AND using some other parameters which are the actual parameters of my-fun (this part fails...)

How can I do this? I think the problem is that a and b are not evaluated before the macro expansion and when the macro is expanded Lisp searches for a local a and b but there is no a or b. Is there any way to evaluate a and b? (so the macro could treat them like concrete values)

This is the macro def: (written by another programmer)

```
(defmacro* my-commandsend-and-reply-macro ((cmd &rest args) &body body)
`(progn
  (with-request-id ()
   (setf (gethash *request-id* *my-callbacks*)
         (lambda (status &rest status-args)
           (case status
             ,@(loop for (kind . clause) in body when (eql kind :reply)
                 collect 
                 (destructuring-bind 
                    ((status-flag &rest lambda-form-pattern) 
                                    &body action-given-by-user) clause
                   `(,status-flag
                      (destructuring-bind ,lambda-form-pattern status-args
                        ,@action-given-by-user))))
             ((error)
               (message "Error: %s" (elt (elt status-args 0) 1))))))
               (apply #'send-command-to-process *request-id* cmd args)))))
```

Def of with-request-id:

```
(defmacro* with-request-id ((&rest vars) &body body)
  "Send `getid' to the server, and call `body' once the response
with the new ID has arrived. By then, global variable `*request-id*'
is bound to the latest request ID."
`(progn
  (when (not (server-is-running))
        (error "Server isn't running!"))
  (when *reqid-queue*
        (error "Some internal error occured. Please, restart the program!"))
  (lexical-let (,@(loop for var in vars
                       collect `(,var ,var)))
    (setf *reqid-queue* (lambda ()
                         (unwind-protect
                             (progn ,@body)
                           (setf *reqid-queue* nil)))))
  (get-id)))
```

And getting id from the other process:

```
(defun get-id ()
  (send-command-to-process 'getid))
```

Comment: You'd do far better to *show* the macro as well (or a demonstrative version thereof), rather than just trying to describe it. And I'm really not sure what this means: `send a command like i (like do-something) n my-fun (this is ok)`

Comment: I agree with @phils. Try to show what you have tried so far -- the exact code. Say what happens with it and what you expect/want to happen instead.

Comment: As it is mentioned in my question, I tried to use "my-commandsend-and-reply-macro" and its ":reply" part defining my own callback function. In the callback I need to use some variables (see the example, like variable "a" and "b" of my-fun used in do-something).

What happens: the variables aren't evaluated, and Lisp says that there is no variable "a" or "b" (maybe cause of dynamic scoping) because it searches for them where the macro is expanded.

I would like to have a workaround for this.

Comment: What is `defmacro*`, in comparison with `defmacro`?

Comment: Emacs gave the following (using the 'Describe' function):


defmacro* is a Lisp macro.

(defmacro* NAME ARGLIST [DOCSTRING] BODY...)

Define NAME as a macro.
Like normal `defmacro', except ARGLIST allows full Common Lisp conventions,
and BODY is implicitly surrounded by (block NAME ...).

Comment: One main difference is that `defmacro*` lets you use argument destructuring, i.e., pattern matching; `defmacro` does not.

Comment: Are you sure you copied your code correctly? `my-fun` is missing a final `)`, and should `my-commandsend-and-reply-macro` have a `)` after `:repl`? And should that be `:reply`, not `:repl`? And I guess you meant `with-request-id`, not `with-refac-id`? (I'm not taking the time to look at the code carefully -- just scanning it quickly.)

Comment: Drew, you are right, I corrected those mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Without looking into your code at all (apologies -- no time) ---

`a` and `b` ***are*** evaluated by the function `my-fun`.   *All* functions evaluate their arguments to *begin* with -- only macros and special forms do not necessarily evaluate all of their arguments.

But those `a` and `b` values are *not passed* to the macro -- the only thing passed to it is the  unevaluated *sexp* that is bound to `cmd`. And you do not even define `cmd` in your function!

What you need to do is substitute the *values* of `a` and `b` into the `cmd` sexp. You have not shown how `cmd` is defined/constructed, at all.  Construct it using the values of `a` and `b`, and you should be OK.

To construct the `cmd` sexp, remember that you can use backquote syntax to simplify things, using comma syntax to pass the *values* of `a` and `b`. E.g.

```el
 (let ((cmd  `(some funny (expression) that ((uses)) ,a AND ,b)))
   code-that-uses-CMD)
```

This assumes that the code you pass to the macro does not need the *variables* `a` and `b`, and it needs only their *values*.

Comment: or perhaps ``(let ((cmd `(some ... ',a ',b ))) ... )``.

Comment: @WillNess -- Yes, probably so.

Answer (score 1):

When the function `my-fun` is called the arguments have already been evaluated so it's not clear to me what is the problem you are facing.

The only strange thing I see is that the macro is un-hygienic and so if your arguments are named instead of `a` and `b` for example `status` or `status-args` you're going to be in trouble because the expression

```
(do-something <a> <b> results)
```

will be compiled in a context where those names have been reused by the macro.